React Quill , unable to access import of Quill.import
in below code i have some time document not defined issue but now i am getting import is not a function in Quill , i have tried everything also visited every forum but no solution.
this is nextjs and i what i want to do is mention below -
'use client'

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import QuillToolbar, { formats, modules } from './EditorToolbar';

// Import ReactQuill dynamically
const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import('react-quill'), { ssr: false });

const QuillWrapper = ({ value, setEditorValue, readOnly }) => {
 const [enableEditor, setEnableEditor] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {

     import('react-quill').then(({ Quill }) => {
       const Size = Quill.import('formats/size');
       Size.whitelist = ['extra-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large'];
       Quill.register(Size, true);

       const Font = Quill.import('formats/font');
       Font.whitelist = [
         'arial',
         'comic-sans',
         'courier-new',
         'georgia',
         'helvetica',
         'lucida'
       ];
       Quill.register(Font, true);
     });
   
 }, []);

 return (
   <>
     {enableEditor && (
       <>
         <QuillToolbar />
         <ReactQuill
           theme="snow"
           value={value}
           onChange={setEditorValue}
           readOnly={readOnly}
           modules={modules}
           formats={formats}
         />
       </>
     )}
   </>
 );
};

export default QuillWrapper;

i want to -

resize image
add more font size
add more font family
tooltip on toolbar icons

please can someone tell me how to do this.

I have found a
'use client'

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import QuillToolbar, { formats, modules } from './EditorToolbar';

const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import('react-quill'), { ssr: false });

const ReactTextEditor = ({ value, setEditorValue }) => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const Quill = require('react-quill').Quill;
      if (Quill) {
        console.log('Quill instance', Quill);
        const Size = Quill.import('formats/size');
        Size.whitelist =  ['14', '20', '28', '32', '40'];
        Quill.register(Size, true);
        
        const Font = Quill.import('formats/font');
        Font.whitelist = [
          'arial',
          'comic-sans',
          'courier-new',
          'georgia',
          'helvetica',
          'lucida'
        ];
        Quill.register(Font, true);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <QuillToolbar />
      <ReactQuill
        theme="snow"
        value={value}
        onChange={setEditorValue}
        modules={modules}
        formats={formats}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default ReactTextEditor;

